# How to read Windows.UI.XAML.Style properties in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am writing a class that will convert a HTML document to a list of Paragrpahs that can be used with RichTextBlock in Windows 8 apps. I want to be able to give the class a list of Styles defined in XAML and the class will read useful properties from the style and apply them.

If I have a Windows.UI.XAML.Style `style` how do I read a property from it? I tried

```
var fontWeight = style.GetValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty)
```

for a `style` defined in XAML with TargetProperty="TextBlock" but this fails with and exception

Comment: Not an answer to the question explicitly, but would you actually need to read the styles when you apply them to your parsed text? I would imagine that you would use keyed styles to apply to text spans from HTML based on the formatting in HTML?

Comment: @FilipSkakun what do you mean by keyed styles? I would ignore all the style in the actual HTML and I want to apply my styles defined in XAML to the transformed output

Comment: Oh, I see - like reusing your textblock styles for paragraphs when paragraphs and inlines don't support styles? It might not be possible. You could perhaps use DataTemplates instead of styles. Like <DataTemplate x:Name="boldTextRunTemplate"><Run FontWeight="Bold"/>... then do var boldRun = (Run)boldTextRunTemplate.LoadContent()

Comment: @FilipSkakun yes, I do not want the class to have the style hardcoded but I want the caller to be able to give the class any styles he wants. Using style defined in XAML is better that creating them in code and passing them to the class. Using a DataTemplate is not an option, you can have more nested style, like <b><i>hello</i>world</b> and defining an DataTemplate for each of them is insane.

Comment: Good point. I guess if noone knows an answer to your question you could define some sort of a custom style implementation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
var fontWeightSetter =
    style.Setters.Cast<Setter>().FirstOrDefault(
        setter => setter.Property == TextElement.FontWeightProperty);

var fontWeight =
    fontWeightSetter != null ?
        (FontWeight)fontWeightSetter.Value :
        FontWeights.Normal;
```

Or check if that works:

```
public static class StyleExtensions
{
    // Untested
    public static object GetPropertyValue(this Style style, DependencyProperty property)
    {
        var setter =
            style.Setters.Cast<Setter>().FirstOrDefault(
                s => s.Property == property);
        var value = setter != null ? setter.Value : null;

        if (setter == null &&
            style.BasedOn != null)
        {
            value = style.BasedOn.GetPropertyValue(property);
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I'll add it to the toolkit. :)

Comment: Hi, is there a way to assign the return value of GetPropertyValue (which is a BindingExpressionBase) into style properties like TextBlock.FontFamily. Thanks.

Comment: So this method gives you a `BindindExpressionBase` as a result? I assume this must be WPF or Silverlight? I don't think WinRT has that. I would ask a separate question.