# Reading Windows.UI.XAML.Style properties in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to convert a HTML string into RichTextBlock content. In order to do so I am using inlines and I want to set style properties of these inlines using styles defined in XAML.

I have searched for a solution and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088851/how-to-read-windows-ui-xaml-style-properties-in-c-sharp). However this code returns `BindindExpressionBase` as a result and I can't set it to Run properties directly. I tried different methods but failed to do so.

This is my XAML.

```
<Style x:Key="RTCodeStyle" TargetType="HyperlinkButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseRichTextBlockStyle}">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Courier New" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource TextStyleLargeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
</Style>
```

and this is what I want to achieve.

```
Run r = new Run();
r.FontFamily = style.GetPropertyValue(RichTextBlock.FontFamilyProperty);
r.FontSize = style.GetPropertyValue(RichTextBlock.FontSizeProperty);
r.Foreground = style.GetPropertyValue(RichTextBlock.ForegroundProperty);
```

This code causes `Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.FontFamily'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)` error. Trying to cast the return value to `RichTextBlock.FontFamilyProperty` causes `'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.RichTextBlock.FontFamilyProperty' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'` error.

The body of GetPropertyValue (from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13091215/252738)) is

```
public static class StyleExtensions
{
    public static object GetPropertyValue(this Style style, DependencyProperty property)
    {
        var setter =style.Setters.Cast<Setter>().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Property == property);
        var value = setter != null ? setter.Value : null;

        if (setter == null &&style.BasedOn != null)
            value = style.BasedOn.GetPropertyValue(property);
        return value;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any helps in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you have to actually cast it as a element you're interested of?

```
r.FontFamily = (FontFamily)style.GetPropertyValue(RichTextBlock.FontFamilyProperty);
r.FontSize = (FontSize)style.GetPropertyValue(RichTextBlock.FontSizeProperty);
r.Foreground = (Brush)style.GetPropertyValue(RichTextBlock.ForegroundProperty);
```

Comment: Unfortunetely this also causes an exception. `Cannot cast 'style.GetPropertyValue(RichTextBlock.FontFamilyProperty)' (which has an actual type of 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.BindingExpressionBase') to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.FontFamily'`

Comment: @BirkanCilingir: Cast it to `BindingExpressionBase` and then you have access to `Target`, and `TargetProperty` properties, which then help you to actually read the value using reflection?

Comment: `BindingExpressionBase` class belongs to `Windows.UI.Xaml.Data` namespace (not `System.Windows.Data`) and it doesn't contain `Target` and `TargetProperty`. Also even that class doesn't seem to have a `Value`, which makes me think that my method is not right from the beginning.